# PHP code inside javascript being triggered by REFRESH instead of onClick

Tags: php, javascript, toggle

This code is meant to toggle chat on/off

The problem is, it toggles chat on/off every time I REFRESH the page, and it should trigger with a onClick href, like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chat_toggle">Enable Chat</a>



<!-- Show/Hide Chat -->
<?php if ((get_option('show_chat') != "")):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
       $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.chat_toggle').click(function(){
             document.write("<?php update_option("show_chat",""); ?>");
    });

});
</script>
<?php elseif ((get_option('show_chat') === "")):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
       $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.chat_toggle').click(function(){
             document.write("<?php update_option("show_chat","1"); ?>");
    });

});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a better way to code it?

Comment: You do realize that you can't `document.write()` PHP code and have PHP code execute in the browser client right?

Comment: There's probably ***only*** better ways to code this ?

Comment: @MikeBrant - as long as `update_option()` outputs a string for `document.write` to write, sure you can, but when writing to the document, everything else dissapears ?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is processed on the server side and Javascript is processed on the client side.  Because of this, when you try to add PHP dynamically using document.write, the PHP won't be executed (it's not seen by the server at this point).

It looks like what you need to do is take whatever functionality is done in the call to update_option, and replace it with javascript.  If there's something that absolutely must be updated on the server side when that option is set, you can do it with an AJAX call, but still need to handle the front-end functionality in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="chat_toggle">Enable Chat</a>

<!-- Show/Hide Chat -->
<script type="text/javascript">
       var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
       $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.chat_toggle').click(function(){

<?php if (!empty(get_option('show_chat'))) { ?>

  //you need to add ajax call in here to update the options

<?php 
}
else { ?>

  //you need to add ajax call in here to update the options

<?php } ?>


   });

});
</script>
```

you need to add ajax call to update your options value, you can't simply use document.write.. jquery comes with an easy powerful ajax functions. There are plenty of examples of how to accomplish it.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Unfortunately: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /wp-content/themes/criatweb/header.php on line 179 <?php if (!empty(get_option('show_chat'))) { ?>